# How do you copy data from a table for one user and insert it into another user within the same database using mysql?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do a high load test and I need to take existing user data in our sandbox and add it to newly created users. I've never had to do this before and just want to save time so our testers don't have to create a bunch of new data through the ui. I need to do something like this but I am having a hard time figuring it out from the documents.

```
INSERT INTO `shipment`
VALUES (SELECT *  FROM `shipment` 
    WHERE `userId` = 20 
    AND `status` = 'READY' 
WHERE `userId` = 236
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html

Comment: Almost...drop the VALUES and the bracket. And also name your fields explicitly rather than using * - for one thing you probably don't want to be copying the ID field

Comment: You should also avoid using * in the SELECT statement - list the columns explicitly.